# How can I attach this throwable spear to my characters hands and be able to have him throw it?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm a beginner to unity and I have a few questions.
I have tried looking for a similar solution but pretty much all of them are for unity 3d and they already have the "weapon" as a part of their character body.
I have written a script for a pull back and throw spear but now I'm wondering how I can attach it to my characters hands and make the pull back mechanic be restricted by his arms and fully attached. Any help would be appreciated. Gif and code is below:

GIF:https://gfycat.com/insistentbestdogwoodclubgall

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;
 
public class spear : MonoBehaviour
{
 
   
 
    public Rigidbody2D mySpear;
   
    Vector3 velocity;
 
    private Vector3 _initialPosition;
 
    [SerializeField] private float _launchPower = 500;
 
   
 
   
 
    private float _timeSittingAround;
 
    private bool _spearWasLaunched;
 
 
 
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;
 
        mySpear = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
 
    void Start()
    {
        mySpear = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       
    }
 
 
   
 
    //reloads the scene if spear goes out of bounds or lays dormant for 2 seconds
    void Update()
    {
     
 
     
        //rotates the spear in the direction it's moving
        mySpear.transform.up =
        Vector3.Slerp(mySpear.transform.up, mySpear.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.normalized, Time.deltaTime);
 
 
 
        if (_spearWasLaunched &&
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude <= 0.1)
        {
            _timeSittingAround += Time.deltaTime;
        }
     
        if(transform.position.y > 30 ||
            transform.position.y < -12.5 ||
            transform.position.x > 40 ||
            transform.position.x < -20 ||
            _timeSittingAround > 2)
        {
            string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
        }
     
    }
 
    //slingshot mechanic
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
       
    }
 
   
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
       
       
       
    }
 
 
 
    //launches the spear when mouse is released
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
 
       
 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * _launchPower);
 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;
 
        _spearWasLaunched = true;
 
       
 
 
 
       
 
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from 3D gaming, but the concept should be pretty similar:

- Rig your character for animations
- Nest the spear game object under the hand transform of the character
- Use IK to set the hand to where the spear is pulled to; add a constraint that if the player is trying to pull too far don't let him
- When the mouse is released, unnest the spear from the hand and launch it